# Priority value in FreeRTOS xTaskCreate() method

Tags: c, api, freertos

I can not seem to find what a priority value passed to task creation functions of FreeRTOS mean. If I remember correctly ThreadX uses smaller values for higher priorities i.e task with priority value 1 has higher priority value than task with priority value 2. But for FreeRTOS I cant seem to find whether if it is the same or if it is the opposite i.e higher value meaning higher priority.

I have tried googling but couldn't find anything. [FreeRTOS API reference page for xTaskCreate](http://www.freertos.org/a00125.html) only specifies that this is the priority value. Can some one please help resolve this confusion.

Comment: You may have to go dig through the source of the scheduler.

Comment: @woolstar That is what I am hoping to avoid :) There must be few ppl here with good knowledge of FreeRTOS

Comment: Idle task's priority value is 0 (tskIDLE_PRIORITY) so I think smaller value means lower priority.

Answer (score 13):

Found answer to my question in FreeRTOS Quick start guide. The [section on task priorities](http://www.freertos.org/RTOS-task-priority.html) explains that lower priority numbers denote lower priority tasks and idle task has priority zero which is the lowest priority.